# Bohr radius question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, orbital-motion, atomic-physics

I'm doing a homework problem where it asks to calculate the diameter of a hydrogen atom with $n=600$. I used the equation $r=\frac{n^2a_0}{Z}$ where $a_0=0.529e^{-10}m$.

Solving for $r$ yields:

$$r=\frac{(600^2)(0.529e^{-10}m)}{1}=1.90e^{-5}m$$

Multiplying by 2 to get the diameter yields:

$$d=2r=2(1.90e^{-5}m)=3.80e^{-5}m$$

However, the answer given says that $d=1.90e^{-5}m$, but how can this be? I know that the equation above yields the radius of an electron's orbit, but why would they claim that it's the diameter? Thoughts??

Comment: Any valid reason for the downvote?

Comment: @Nogueira Full problem: With the aid of tunable lasers, Rydberg atoms of sodium have been produced
with $n=100$. The resulting atomic diameter would correspond in hydrogen to $n= 600$.
(a) What would be the diameter of a hydrogen atom whose electron is in the $n = 600$
orbit?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rydberg_state

Comment: Look this too: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rydberg_matter

Answer (score 1):

You have identified the problem as the factor $2$ between your calculation and the book.  You have read the problem correctly, so it seems the book is wrong.

Comment: That's what I was thinking as well, but this is the 6th edition of Modern Physics. Eh, oh well.